# Blob URLs with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, blob, bloburls

I'm trying to figure out why the request i send gives me this error :

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'blob:https://192.168.56.108/7020557a-95f0-4560-a3d4-94e23bc3db4a'
```

In another thread, i read that it was due to `https` missing. But in my url i still do have it. Here is the code i wrote to send the request :

```
url_image = 'blob:https://192.168.56.108/7020557a-95f0-4560-a3d4-94e23bc3db4a'
headers = {'Origin': 'https://192.168.56.108',
                'Referer':'',
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/105.0.1343.27'}                              
response = s.get(url_image, stream=True, verify=False)
print(response.url)
```

I also read in another thread that blob url where generated by the browser once the page is loaded. So i thought a doing a GET request to the page where i would usually download first then sending the POST request but it doesn't work still. I thought it could be for the fact that the `blob url` was not the one associated to the page i loaded (a new one would have been generated).

For a bit more **context**, i load a page on which there is a graphic that i can download. To check what happens, i use the network console. What happens is that each time i click and download that graphic. A GET request is made with a blob URL that changes each time i download.

So my question is more how to get the correct url with python requests and why would i get the first error when sending the request to the `blob url` ?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding blob objects are binary objects often stored in the source code. (Usualyy a m3u8 play list.) The only solution I have found thus far is to use insepct to find the request for the m3u8 file (on the network tab). Then you can download the video files and build the video with python. However, if you're wanting to trace the blob programtically currently the only option I have found is to use selenium to control a headless browser and search the traffic for the m3u8 file.

Comment: Also if the urls are generated with javascript you need the headless browser to run the javascript.